# How to replicate week number that was generated using Redshift's to_char on Snowflake?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-redshift, week-number, to-char

I'm trying to migrate a Redshift SQL script to Snowflake and trying to emulate week number on Snowflake. Below is the sample Redshift code:

```
select  cast(to_char('2020-01-06'::date, 'WW') as int)  as week,
        cast(to_char('2020-01-06'::date, 'IW') as int)  as iso_week,
        '2020-01-06'::date;
```

The closest functions I found on Snowflake was like this:

```
select cast(WEEKOFYEAR('2020-01-06'::date) as int)  as week,
       cast(WEEKISO('2020-01-06'::date) as int)     as iso_week,
       '2020-01-06'::date;
```

`iso_week` fields are matching, however `week` doesn't [Redshift shows 1, Snowflake shows 2]. Is there any function that emulates Redshift's behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of `WW` on Redshift

> WW: Week number of year (1–53; the first week starts on the first day of the year.)

Then the equivalent is to get the "day of year", and divide by 7 to count the number of weeks. We will also need some +/- ones to account for base 0:

```sql
select 1+floor((dayofyear('2020-01-06'::date)-1)/7)
-- 1
```

In UDF form:

```sql
create or replace function weeknumber_ww(x date) 
returns int
as $$
    1+floor((dayofyear(x)-1)/7)
$$
;

select weeknumber_ww('2020-01-06');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is depenedent on parameter [WEEK_OF_YEAR_POLICY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#week-of-year-policy)

> Specifies how the weeks in a given year are computed.
>
> 0: The semantics used are equivalent to the ISO semantics, in which a week belongs to a given year if at least 4 days of that week are in that year.
>
> 1: January 1 is included in the first week of the year and December 31 is included in the last week of the year.

Comment: Setting this variable to 0 or 1 doesn't change behavior on Snowflake. It always returns 2. Even setting `WEEK_START` doesn't change behavior.

Comment: @MajidAzimi in both instances the resulting comparison is true which is why there is no difference.  jan 1 2020 is a wed, there are 4 days in the week . You will have to change the week start.  `alter session set week_start = 2;`